# Unable to isolate hardware issue

Tags: hardware-failure

I am having trouble with my gaming PC, I can turn it on and the CPU fan spins, MOBO Lights are on but it never reaches the BIOS boot screen and my monitors and peripherals get no power.

I have been trying to fix it all day today, and I have overall removed everything, such as the MOBO from the case, disconnected everything except the CPU and PSU and Internal Speaker.

Occasionally it starts and beeps asking me to put in RAM/Keyboard and I have occasionally managed to get the BIOS screen up, but it seems to go from a working state to a non working state with no changes at all, it seems either the CPU or the Motherboard is broken, but I can't establish which as I can't switch out those two items.

I suspected a short circuit, but even while operating on a box removed from the PC it can sometimes work, but more often not.

How can I determine if the CPU or the Motherboard is the cause.

Comment: There's too many variables to solve your equation.  Unless you have working parts you can use to find out which one of yours is failing, I wouldn't know how you could isolate.

Comment: Have you tried testing with individual ram chips, or different slots? That’s the other component you didn’t mention. If the system POSTs at all, I don’t think it is the motherboard or CPU. But definitely RAM can cause this.